# How do I create a generic method with a generic in the where clause? (Man that's clear as mud!)

Tags: c#, generics, eventaggregator

Is there a way of doing this:

```
protected void SubscribeToEvent<TEvent, TPayload>(Action<TPayload> a_action)
    where TEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<TPayload>
{
    TEvent newEvent = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TEvent>();
    SubscriptionToken eventToken = newEvent.Subscribe(a_action);

    _lstEventSubscriptions.Add(new KeyValuePair<EventBase, SubscriptionToken>(newEvent, eventToken));
}
```

without requiring the user to specify a `TPayload` parameter?

Comment: Does `Generic Craziness` provide any insight whatsoever as to the question? How do you plan to attract good answers? How are subsequent searchers going to find this question when they are faced with a similar problem? Try to use meaningful questions the same way you would want meaningful class and method names in your code.

Comment: I'm usually more clear.  Its a complex situation.  How would you phrase the question?  :)

Comment: Didn't say it was easy! Start with "multiple generic type parameter inference" and work from there.

Comment: Oh we edited the title within 2 secs of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Not in C# 4. You can't do that with a single method.

`TEvent` cannot be inferred from the arguments passed to the method, and since partial inference is not available for generic type arguments, you'll have to manually specify the type argument at call site.

Comment: +1 PS I think OP thought `TPayload` can be inferred from `TEvent` because of the `where` constraint, but it's not part of C# type inference phases.

Comment: The OP (a.k.a. me) did think that. I need to create a method that accepts any composite event.  I can't use `EventBase` because it doesn't have a `Subscribe` method which is the whole point of the method in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, **VB.NET** has something very much like this for **extension methods**.

Say I have the following extension method:

```
<Extension()>
Function Append(Of TInferred, T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TInferred)) As Object()
    Dim items As List(Of Object) = source.Cast(Of Object).ToList()

    Dim value As T = Nothing ' equivalent to default(T) '
    items.Add(value)

    Return items.ToArray()
End Function
```

Then I could actually call this method passing a *single* type parameter, for `T` only, with `TInferred` being inferred:

```
Dim strings = New String() {"A", "B", "C"}

' Notice I am passing only one type argument. '
Dim objects = strings.Append(Of Integer)()

For Each obj As Object In objects
    Console.WriteLine(obj)
Next
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
0
```

Sadly, [as Mehrdad has indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556576/how-do-i-create-a-generic-method-with-a-generic-in-the-where-clause-man-thats/4556597#4556597), this is not possible in C#.

Comment: What about this can not be done in C#?  We've got extension methods too.  From what I've seen C# and VB are 90% functionally the same. Our syntax is just a little less obscure (kidding -- former VB'er). Doesn't solve my problem though.  I think my problem is that I'm trying to make generics too generic. The type arguments are supposed to be specific.

Comment: @Jordan: In C#, you cannot define a generic extension method with *two* generic type parameters and have *one* of them be inferred. Notice in the `Append` method from my example, it is defined with two type parameters but called with only one. C# doesn't have that—that's what I was trying to convey, though maybe I didn't do the greatest job.

Comment: @Jordan: Also, you're right—it still wouldn't answer your question. It was more of a "here's an interesting/somewhat relevant tidbit to know" kind of answer (I mean, it's VB after all...).